# How can I deactivate the close button on GUI of the file explorer in Windows OS?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, batch-file, user-folders

If I open up a Folder in Windows OS. Is it possible to prevent the user from closing the folder by clicking on the red close icon on the top right corner of the GUI of file explorer?

I want to password protect my folder such that whenever, the user closes the folder, the folder automatically get renamed.

Is this possible to do so on Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer is no. Not without using some kind of third-party software that hooks into explorer.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "password protect" and then rename the folder. But as far as I know there is no easy way to attach an event (i.e. rename) to an action like close window.

Comment: Thank you for yor answer- can you back this up with a reference or othher information? :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to back up a negative other than to say if you look in the Login settings for the user or even in the Group Policy editor, there are ways to assign things to run for Login, Logout, and shutdown but nothing for File/Folder changes. Permissions can be allowed and/or denied for files and folders too but no way to assign an action to an event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
What I have done so far is that using the bat file i am making a folder which I have hidden. Now, what I want is that whenever a user closes down this folder, I want to trigger a bat file that will rename that folder and hides it so that user cant access that folder with its original name.
Is this possible to do so in anyway?